# setOnClickListener onTouchEvent

Tags: java, android

I have an onTouchEvent on a Linearlayout which has multiple Views(Rows).
When I set an setOnClickListener to the child views of my Linearlayout onTouchEvent on the Linearlayout won't work anymore. I just performs the setOnClickListener of the child views.

I need the event.getY(); for my own smoothscroller. I add the delta movement to my scrollpoint and with that scrollpoint variable I set my items in the list. It should become an own recyclerview with endlessscroll already implemented, Is it possible to get that information out of the scrollview? Sorry for my bad English.

```
public class ScrollLinearLayout extends LinearLayout {
....
public void init(Context context) {

  for (int i = 0; i < visiblerows; i++) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, this);
        }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
     ... do scrolling here
}


..other class
public class mylayout extends ScrollLinearLayout {
...
@Override
    public void onUpdate(int position, View v)
    {
        String item=locallist.get(position);
        TextView text =(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textviewID);
        text.setText(item);

       v.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {

           }
       });

    }
```

Comment: Why not wrap `ScrollView` in `LinearLayout`? I mean, if the intention is merely to scroll the contents of `LinearLayout`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.